# Find Smith's normal form of $\begin{pmatrix} 7\theta-14 & \theta^2/2-2\theta+3\\ \theta^2 - 4\theta + 6 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, smith-normal-form

I need to find the Smith Normal form of
$\begin{pmatrix}
7\theta-14 & \theta^2/2-2\theta+3\\
\theta^2 - 4\theta + 6 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. This is a sub problem of a bigger problem. The problem with this is that I don't see how the standard algorithm can work here. If I multiply first column by some polynomial and add to second row then $0$ changes and it doesn't change to something good, because I simply get a polynomial of a degree of $3$ there and this will keep going endlessly. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the gcd of all elements?put that in position 1,1  either by row or column operations. For a start, what is $\gcd( 7 \theta - 14, \theta^2 - 4 \theta +6)$   Evidently you are already allowing rational coefficients

Comment: using the euiclidean algorithm I get 2 as gcd. also, as $a_{21} = 2a_{12}$, then $gcd(a_{11},a_{12})=4$. Finally $gcd(a_{12}, a_{21}) = a_{12}$

Comment: find polynomials with $a_{11} p(x)  +  a_{12}q(x) = 1,$ make a matrix $R_1=  \left( \begin{array}{cc} p & -a_{12} \\q & a_{11}   \end{array} \right)  $  and calculate matrix $A_1 = A  R_1.$   The letter $R$ stands for "right."  Multiplying on the right does column operations   Another two matrices should finish it

Comment: @WillJagy btw, now I've thought, we know that Smith's form is unique because it can be retrieved using the minors. For example, the value on the $(1,1)$ cell in Smith's normal form should be the $gcd$ of all 1-minors shouldn't it? If so, then it is $2$, then the only 2-minor is the determinant of the matrix itself and the value on $(2,2)$ is that determinant divided by $2$, isn't it?

Comment: Well, since you included a polynomial with a fraction as a coefficient, I concluded that this all happens with rational coefficients. If so, the typical thing is to take a constant gcd as $1.$ The ring $\mathbb Q[x]$ is Euclidean. Meanwhile, I really encourage you to work out everything with explict matrices $R_j$    for colun operations and $L_k$ for row operations. In the end you have explicit products $L$ and $R$   such that $LAR=S$  is Smith. You are going to remember this much better if you write out all the matrices.

Comment: @WillJagy late update. So there was a problem in the exam that required finding Smith's normal form of the matrix. In the end I solved it using the minors and I didn't lose any points from that problem so I suppose it is ok to solve it using the minors. Now I'm thinking that as we are working with polynomials then it is ok anyways to write 1 for every non-zero zero-degree polynomial in the Smith's form, so it must be ok to solve this using the minors. Your approach is much more rigorous I guess and I should give a try.

Comment: @WillJaggy Yet I think the Minors "trick" is underrated, because it's the essence behind Smith's Normal form.

Comment: H, as with diagonalization, Jordan form, any change of basis, one might be able to find the final matrix $S$   from extra conditions. However, there are situations where it is necessary to know a correct change of basis matrix $P$  that takes a square matrix $A$   to $P^{-1}AP = D$   is diagonal, or sometimes   $P^{-1}AP = J$  is Jordan.  This is necessary for simply finding $A^n$   for large exponent $n.$  It is also necessary for solving ODE system $x' = A x $  and calculating $e^{At}.$   If you are unable to find the cjange of basis matrix $P$ you are out of luck